# Rails: Syntaxerror - Unexpected '{' in sessionscontroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have cloned a quiz app project from this repo: https://github.com/Pk13055/quiz-app

I am trying to run it from my system by using this command:

`rails server`

But I am getting this error:

```
/home/lucky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting end ...ion only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_tim... ... ^ /home/lucky/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end ..."devise.skip_timeout"] = true } ... ^
Extracted source (around line #5):

  prepend_before_action :allow_params_authentication!, only: :create
  prepend_before_action :verify_signed_out_user, only: :destroy
  prepend_before_action only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
```

How can I rectify this error and make the application run?

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create]
  prepend_before_action :allow_params_authentication!, only: :create
  prepend_before_action :verify_signed_out_user, only: :destroy
  prepend_before_action only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end
```

Comment: can you post your sessions_controller.rb ?

Comment: I have added `sessions_controller.rb` file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems there's a problem with Ruby 2.5+ and devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4630.

Apparently devise 4.4.0 has fixed it, but you are using v4.3.0 (check your Gemfile.lock). You need to update it:

```sh
bundle update devise
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lamda, in line5

```
prepend_before_action -> { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }, only: [:create, :destroy]
```